# Union Bound for a Random Number of Events

Tags: probability-theory

Is it possible to generalize the union bound to a random number of events, similar to Wald's equation about a random number of terms in a sum? In particular, how can I bound something like
$$
 \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^Z \mathcal{A}_i \right),
$$
where $Z$ is a random variable.

Answer (score 2):

Let $B_n = A_n \backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i$, and $t_n = \mathbb P(B_n)$.  If $X_n$ is the indicator random variable of $B_n$,

$$\mathbb P\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^Z A_i\right) = \mathbb E \left[ \sum_{i=1}^Z X_i \right] = \mathbb E\left[ \sum_{i=1}^Z t_i \right]$$

Comment: Thanks. Does the first step assume anything? Because the second step should be precisely Wald's equation (which only applies under certain conditions)? Christian

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems with finiteness.  I think you do have to assume that $Z$ is a "stopping time", i.e. $Z = n$ is independent of $\{X_j: j > n\}$.

Comment: Could you please expand on why exactly the first equality holds? As pointed out by @TriSSSe, it does not seem to be trivial.